# Can't build Azure Functions project from dotnet CLI

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, appveyor

I'm having some troubles with a newly created Azure Functions project (the new precompiled version). It's a `TimerTrigger` function which I created from template in VS2017.

It builds just fine from within Visual Studio, but when I try to build it with the .NET Core CLI (msbuild) I get the following error:

> C:\Users\f00.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.2\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(31,5): error : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Repos\Test\testproject\src\functions-project\functions-project.csproj]
>
> Version: "Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core"

My guess is that when building from within VS it uses a different version of msbuild, or a different configuration. But I'm not sure how to fix it. The end goal here is being able to build and deploy with Appveyor, but I get the same error there of course.

**Update**

I've tried creating a new functions project and a `TimerTrigger` from scratch, but to no avail - getting the same error again. I even tried creating an `HttpTrigger`but that didn't work either :(

Comment: Try to run `dotnet restore` before building in CLI. In terms of AppVeyor it is `before_build` script.

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

As ilyaf metioned that we need to add the before build script `dotnet restore`, I test it on my side, it works corretly. Following is my detail steps.

1.Create an Azure function project with VS2017 template.

2.Push it to the github.

3.Add the project to Appveyor

[image]

4.Set the environment and build

[image]

[image]

5. Check that it build successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. However, running dotnet restore prior to dotnet build yields the same results. I guess I will have to resort to creating a brand new functions project and see if I can get different results. Cheers!